# Set width of a div in respect to height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div `#slideshow` with images of 2:1 aspect ratio. So, set height of image I am using jQuery:

> Note: The Slideshow Div is 100% wide with respect to browser window. If user makes the browser window, smaller - it is going to be smaller.

```
slideWidth();

function slideWidth(){
var width = $("#slideshow").css("width");
var height = (parseInt(width.substr(0,width.length-2)) /3);
$("#slideshow").css("height",height+"px");
}
```

And, to make the width change dynamically, I use setTimeout:

```
setInterval(slideWidth,1000);
```

This is actually working as I want. But I think I am heavily giving high impact on the website by refreshing the function `slidewidth` every second.

Is this achievable through CSS3? Or with jQuery/JS with less Website Impact?

Thank you. Feel free to comment with new ways/ideas.

Comment: Instead, change it only on the window resize: `$(window).resize(slideWidth);`

Comment: Why refresh every second? You could attach the the window.onresize event instead.

Comment: Thanks, Is this achievable through CSS? Just if you have some ideas.

Comment: Hi @tika, please check my answer for a Css only solution. It may be useful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using jquerys .resize(); This adds an event listener waiting for the container to resize.
Ej:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  //do your logic here
});
```

[Jquery resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: If you belive this is the correct answer please marks it as such for future searchs.

Comment: Thanks, Is this achievable through CSS? Just if you have some ideas

Comment: This isn't triggering on resize for me. However, if I change it to $(window).resize(...) it works.

Comment: Im sorry , its to the windows you should attach it. My mistake. Thank you for pointing it out. Ill edit my answer. It is achievable through css3 with mediaqueries.

Comment: Media queries have nothing to do with this, since it is a fluid issue, not responsive...

Answer (score 4):

There's a css-only approach using pseudo elements and padding:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
}

div:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    padding-top: 50%;
}
```

The combination of the pseudo `padding-top` can be used to vary between aspect ratios.

In this case, the `50%` padding is equivalent to aspect ratio of `2:1`

[**Working Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ssjh4m6e/)